# how to convert from string to integer

Tags: java, android

I have a problem that made me confused, i want to use the value of EditText and convert it to int,
 when launching the activity it displays on logcat "invalid int"
and i make the input value for the editText is 9 digits!
could you help me in finding the problem

this is my code:

```
     String texti =  numberi.getText().toString();
     int x = Integer.parseInt(texti);
```

Comment: Integer x = Integer.valueOf(str);  are u try this?????

Comment: can you do a trim on string before doing parseInt. Just to eliminate any chances of space character or so

Comment: where did u write this code. in `onCreate()` method ?

Comment: yes, the problem that i used this way, and for some reason it doesn't work!!!

Comment: yes i wrote it in OnCreate()

Comment: i tried long, still the same problem, i also checked my xml for the edit text; the input type is number, also i used trim() , still the same, dont know what to do!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u said that u have wrote that in `onCreate()`. so u have to check first, is the text is null or not:

```
String texti =  numberi.getText().toString();
long x;
if(texti.trim().length() > 0)
  x = Long.parseLong(texti);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to save it in `long`

```
long x = Long.parseLong(texti);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your only objective is to allow user to input numbers into EditText.Then use

```
android:inputType="number"
```

And then `Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());`

Answer (score 0):

The integer in `texti` could be larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` value, so use `Long` instead

```
long x = Long.parseLong(texti.trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have code is correct but for better way use this,

```
  String texti =  numberi.getText().toString();
  int x = Integer.parseInt(texti.trim());  // Trim the extra spaces, if any.
```

Always have habbit to trim() when converting to Numeric format, This will prevent from `NumberFormatException`

Answer (score 0):

Parsing String to Integer:

```
    Integer.parseInt(<Your EditText>.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, if your EditText will only accept integers then you should set *inputType* property to either:

- numberSigned
- number

eg. something like this:

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editTextCustomerPin"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:inputType="numberSigned"
        android:textSize="16dp" android:hint="@string/enterCustomerPin"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

Now in your activity, you can always do:

```
EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextCustomerPin);
String editTextContent = myEditText.getText().toString();
if (editTextContent.length() > 0) {
     int num = Integer.parseInt(num);
     //Do your processing
} else {  
     //Show error message, eg. a toast or an alert dialog
}
```